# How does Veil of Discord damage amplification works?

Tags: dota-2

How does it works?

A: Removing a hero's inate 25% magic resistance, leaving them with 0% magic reduction.

B: Amplifying the spell damage by 25%, i.e. 100 damage spell now does 125 damage, then it is reduced by the hero's magic resistance.

C: Reducing the current hero's magic resistance by 25%. Example: Heroes using Hood/Pipe or heroes with skills that gives magic resistance.

D: None of the above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Veil, it "reduces" magic resistance by 25%, but remember since magic damage is calculated multiplicitavely, the enemy will still have 6% magic resistance left over. So you will deal 19% additional magic damage to a hero that had 25% base magic resistance.

Also remember Magic Resistance reduction technically does not exist, but if you hover your mouse over a hero's stats it'll say they've been reduced to 6% when in reality the magic damage is actually amplified to mimic that.

So in short, Magic Damage x 1.25 but the target still has 6% resist if he was a 25% resist hero.

stolen from reddit  http://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/1vbiya/mechanics_how_does_veil_of_discord_amplify_magic/

Comment: This is incorrect : heros' typical base resistance is 25%, not 30%, meaning that the damage is effectively after veil :
(1+0.25)*(1-0.25) = 1-0.0625 = 93.75%.

Dagon will deal 400- 6.25%*400 = 375 damage

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: Not counting Meepo.

Comment: @patchandthat or visage. But when you mention heros' typical magic resistance, you usually don't consider outliers